# Running total of choice data from several lists

Tags: list, jquery, designer-workflow, calculated-column, data

I'm using SP 2010.  I have a few lists that have many of the same set of Choice columns.  I want to be able to output a running total of how many there are of each choice from all lists.  Maybe in a column in a separate list? The idea is to have a master list that totals out data aggregated from other lists.

For example: 
ListA has 3 items where ChoiceA was selected.
ListB has 4 items where ChoiceA was selected.
My output in the master list will show something like "ChoiceA = 7"... and so on.

It seems like a calculated column won't help me here because I am working with many lists and primarily with text values.  I could be wrong though.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: With a Workflow executing on every change. Calculated Columns can only access data from its own Item... it can't access other List Items or even other Lists

Comment: So now the question becomes "How can I use SharePoint Designer workflows to calculate a running total of choice data (strings) and output those totals to another list?"

Comment: I have an if statement that will add 1 to a variable when a certain choice is selected.  I would then like to update an item on the master list with that value.  However, it fails.  I read that you can "mimic" looping in designer.  Then I could go through each item, check for the value, and add to the variable.  There has got to be an easier way to calculate this kind of thing.  Using workflows, I can see this turning into a bigger hassle then I thought it would be to achieve something seemingly simple.

Comment: Then go the CSOM or JSOM route

Comment: Yeah, was trying to avoid that.  However, I'm starting to think it's the only way to go.

Comment: What part of your workflow failed?